How to suppress false unused variable warning?
I am getting false warning about unused variables:

warning: initialization of immutable value '_push' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

However, I cannot remove it or replace it with _ because it changes the behaviour.
Code
struct Test : ~Copyable { 
    init() { print("init") } 
    deinit { print("deinit") } 
}

// case 1
do {
    _ = Test()
    print(1)
}

// case 2
do {
    let _ = Test()
    print(1)
}

// case 3
do {
    let _test = Test() 
    print(1)
}

Output:
init
deinit
1
init
deinit
1
init
1
deinit

Only the case 3 is valid for my use case and the warning is wrong. How do I get rid of the wrong warning?

This also doesn't work
struct Test : ~Copyable {
    init() { print("init") }
    deinit { print("deinit") }
}

func foo(_: consuming Test) {
    print(1)
}

foo(Test())

Still
init
deinit
1


Thanks. Got it working with withExtendedLifetime(Test()) { print(1) }. You want to make it answer?

Did it actually work? In Swift 6? (I don't have Swift 6 yet) I got a "Noncopyable type 'S' cannot be substituted for copyable generic parameter 'T'" error in Swift 5.10, and I had to write a non-generic version of that.

Yes it is working with Swift 6

Interesting, I thought that requires noncopyable generics to work, which has not been implemented as far as I know.

There is a function in the standard library for this exact purpose - withExtendedLifetime.
withExtendedLifetime(Test()) {
    print(1)
}

